# SMB Share Will Not Unmount (OS X)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, network-shares, smb, unmounting

I use to have a Linux server that I had shares on, and I had them mounted on my OS X machine, but I no longer have this server and the shares are still there and they will not unmount (and even force unmounting them does nothing). Is there anything I can do in the command line to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`diskutil unmount /path_to_mount_point`

For example, to unmount a USB key on my system, I would do:

`diskutil unmount /Volumes/myUSB`

You may also need to include `sudo` before the command.

Comment: The problem is they are not mounted anywhere. Currently they only place they are shown is on the desktop (ie Not in the list of connected drives in Finder)

Comment: If they're not mounted why would you want to unmount them? Do you mean the folders are still there? Why not just delete them by moving them to the trash?

Comment: This is what is on my desktop: http://cl.ly/4Hve

Comment: And this is what happens when I drag it to the trash: http://cl.ly/4HJE

Comment: Hmm, OK. So you did try doing `sudo diskutil unmount /Users/<yourUserName>/Desktop/home`, and it still did not work, correct?

Comment: Correct it says "Unmount Failed"

Comment: Well, you can try using the options `-f` or `-l` (so: `unmount -f`) ... other than that I'm stumped. Hope you solve it =/